# How can I insert and retrieve a PHP Constant as part of a sentence into a MySQL Database?

Tags: php

I am trying to store and retrieve data from my Database including some PHP Constants.

I have set the constant so:- `define("COMPANY", "MyCompany");`

I want to use other constants so I can change the values later down the line if I deploy the site elsewhere.

I have tried using php before the insert e.g.
`You can use <?=COMPANY?>" to keep your diary full and win more work...`

But it doesn't work so stuck.

It simply ignores the constant completely.

I would appreciate some help, thanks

Comment: "But it doesn't work so stuck." - what does that mean? What **exactly** is not working?

Comment: Can you give us the line in the code where you are trying to post?

Comment: @NicoHaase when you do echo $text where $text contains `<?=COMPANY?>`, it doesn't output the COMPANY constant

Comment: Database has `You can use <?=COMPANY?>" to keep your diary full and win more work` in it or `You can use " to keep your diary full and win more work`? Also verify you have browser transformation turned off if viewing in phpmyadmin, or view page source if viewing on web page. `<?=COMPANY?>` would not render as browser would see it as an element.

Comment: @YourCommonSense that's obvious, as the constant is resolved on echoing. But James hasn't written anything about echoing

Comment: The only way to concatenate a constant into a string is `"foo " . CONSTANT . " bar"`. There is no syntax for interpolating constants inside strings as if they were variables. `<?= statement ?>` is shorthand for `<?php echo statement; ?>` which sends the result of the statement _to output_.